# CartThrob and PayPal Website Payments Pro - Declined: Timeout processing request

Tags: cartthrob

I have an EE 2.7.3 site running CartThrob Pro 2.5. The site is running on a Nexcess server and we have SSL installed. We set up the gateway values for Paypal Website Payments Pro, and I have tested against the following:

- sandbox with paypal sandbox testing credit card
- live mode with actual paypal values and two different "real" credit cards

In all instances, we are getting the following error: "Declined: Timeout processing request"

I have verified that cURL is enabled. I also tested with the sample cart templates provided by CartThrob. We always get the same error.

Does anyone have advice on what to check or how to troubleshoot this one?

Thanks!
Tim

Answer (score 1):

OK, here is the solution. The form needed an input for the credit card security code. We are not requiring that, but it had to be in there as a hidden input.